# How to make a calculator with carried out result from previous operations using arraylist and while loop in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Trying to make a calculator using arrayList.
user inserts integers and then type add, subtract, multiply, or divide which perform mathematical operations with those integer, and when user types done , programme ends.
Here is the programme:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class just{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String operation;
    int counter;
    int result = 0;

    while(true){ 

        operation = (input.nextLine()).trim();

        if(operation !=null && !operation.isEmpty()){

        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("done")){ break;}

        try{    
            counter = Integer.parseInt(operation);
            element.add(counter);   
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){

            if("add".equalsIgnoreCase(operation)){

                for( int i : element){
                        result += i;

                }

            System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
            element.clear();
            }else if("subtract".equalsIgnoreCase(operation…
                for( int i : element){
                result -= i;
                }

                System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
                element.clear();    

            }else if("multiply".equalsIgnoreCase(operation…
                for( int i : element){
                    result *= i;
                }
                System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
                element.clear();

            }else if("divide".equalsIgnoreCase(operation))…
                for( int i : element){
                    result /= i;    
                }   
                System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
                element.clear();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Put some numbers, then type add , multiply, subtract or divide to get the result, or type done to exit.");
            }   
        }   
        }else{  
            System.out.println("Please either enter an integer or type done.");
        }   
        }
    }
}
```

`Add` and `subtract` work fine. `Multiply` and `divide` work ok also , but if the first operation is `multiply` or `divide` the result becomes `0`, because initial value of variable `result` is 0, alternatively if i make different variable for `multiply` and `divide` with initial value `1` instead of `0`, it still doesn't work , becasue if i make different variable for `multiply` and `divide` then i have to multiply variable `result` with it(because of carried out result of previously `add` and/or `subtract`, and as the initial value of `result` is `0` it will now results `0` all the time.
How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please format your code to something readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
int result = 0;
```

Instead of setting result to 0, make it an `Integer` and set it to `null`.  Then, your first operation should be to check whether `result` is `null`, and if it is, set `result` to the first `int` element in your `ArrayList` (making sure not to use the element twice).